# How can I clean up misaligned columns in text?

Tags: text

I have a C program that outputs two columns, utterly misaligned. The reason for the misalignment is lengths of words in the first column are very different.

I have an output file opened in vi. How do I quickly align these two columns? I am fine with using awk, perl, sed, and not just vi (7.2) toolset. Also, can we have a generic solution for files with more than two columns?

Here is  sample file

```
column1               column2
-------               -------
sdfsdfsddfsdfsdfsdfsd         343r5
dfgdfgdf             234
gdfgdfgdfgdfgf            645
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Presumably you are using `printf` to output the columns in the first place. You can use extra modifiers in your format string to make sure things get aligned.

- To print a column of a specific width (right-justified), add the width before the formatting flag, e.g., "%10s" will print a column of width 10. If your string is longer than 10 characters, the column will be longer than you want, so choose a maximum value. If the string is shorter, it will be padded with spaces.
- To left-justify a column, put a - sign in front, e.g., "%-10s". I like to left-justify strings and right-justify numbers, personally.
- If you are printing addresses, you can change the fill characters from spaces to  zeroes with a leading zero: "%010x".

To give a more in depth example:

```
printf("%-30s %8s %8s\n", "Name", "Address", "Size");
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    printf("%-30s %08x %8d\n", names[i], addresses[i], sizes[i]);
```

This would print three columns like this:

```
Name                            Address     Size
foo                            01234567      346
bar                            9abcdef0     1024
something-with-a-longer-name   0000abcd     2048
```

Answer (score 37):

For a quick-and-dirty fix, pipe it through column:

```
your_program | column -t
```

If you need to include spaces in the column data, then delimit the fields with some character such as "|" and:

```
your_program | column -t -s "|"
```

You can use any character for a delimiter and specify it with the -s switch. Control characters are possible but a little trickier to work with.

But as Jay mentioned you're better off fixing your program to format the output properly.

Comment: You can use a feature of Bash to easily specify control characters, for example Tab: `column -t -s $'\t'`

Comment: Warning: column does not like lines that are "too long", and while `man column` mentions a limitation at 2048 bytes, in practice a couple hundred bytes is enough to choke it (on Debian 8.3 at least).

Answer (score 9):

Here's a awk solution : `c_prog | awk '{ printf("%- 40s %- 40s\n", $1, $2); }'`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do the processing in Vim (as opposed to fixing the generator), install the **superb** [align plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) and run the following:

```
ggVG
\tsp
```

The first command breaks down to `gg` (go to the start of the file), `V` (enter visual line mode), `G` (go to the end of the file).  As a combination, it visually-selects the entire file.  `\tsp` is an Align map that aligns on white-space.

If you prefer to do things at the `:` command line, you can use an alternative separator (e.g. `###`) and use the command-line Align:

```
:%s/\s\+/###/g
:%Align ###
:%s/### //g
```

It's longer, but you may find it more logical/memorable.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small program that solves this problem using Perl.  It also works for multiple columns.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $sep = 2;

sub max {
    my ($a,$b) = @_;
    return $a > $b ? $a : $b;
}

my @rows;
my $cols;
my $max = 0;

while (<>) {
    next if m/^\s*$/;
    my (@cols) = split m'\s+';

    for (@cols) {
        $max = max($max, length);
    }

    $cols = @cols;
    push @rows, \@cols;
}

for (@rows) {
    my $str = join '', (('%-' . ($max+$sep) . 's') x $cols);
    $str .= "\n";
    printf $str, @$_;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just add missing in another answers options:

Emacs with M-x **align-regexp**, M-x **align-string**, etc. read more at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlignCommands

POSIX shell (possibly build-in) command **printf**:

```
while read f1 f2 f3 tail; do printf "%10s %5s | %s" $f1 $f3 $tail; done <file.txt
```