# How to smoothly align text output

Tags: python, text, formatting

Is there anyway to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505311/how-can-i-clean-up-misaligned-columns-in-text) in python?

I have a bunch of misaligned text that essntially looks like this (copied from above linked question) :

```
column1               column2
-------               -------
sdfsdfsddfsdfsdfsdfsd         343r5
dfgdfgdf             234
gdfgdfgdfgdfgf            645
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
Name                            Address     Size
foo                            01234567      346
bar                            9abcdef0     1024
something-with-a-longer-name   0000abcd     2048
```

But I don't know/can't find any similar text and string modifiers equivalents in python.

Comment: The C solution will work if you substitute the `%` string operator for `printf`.

Comment: @MarkRansom So you mean like `print("%8s"....)`?

Comment: The Python 3.x equivalent of C's `printf("%-30s %08x %8d\n", names[i], addresses[i], sizes[i])` is `print("%-30s %08x %8d" % (names[i], addresses[i], sizes[i]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python 3 (2.6+) you should use `str.format()` and not the "%-systax".

```
format_str = '{name:30} {address:08x} {size:8d}'
print(format_str.format(name='Name', address='Address', size='Size')
print(format_str.format(name=names[i], address=addresses[i], size=sizes[i]))
```

For more infos about the `format()` method look [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)