# how to print formatted output on terminal using C?

Tags: c

I have written a code for a Library system in C. And I want to show the output in following manner on terminal on Linux. I tried with "\t" but the output gets disturbed when the string size varies. I want to print it in fixed manner no matter what string size comes.

I want to print output like below- [image]

I tried to print this using "\t" but the format gets disturbed when the string length of book or author gets smaller or larger. Can somebody help me with this??

Comment: You can refer to the site - https://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clean up misaligned columns in text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505311/how-can-i-clean-up-misaligned-columns-in-text)

Answer (score 1):

Print with fixed character size. Here it is 7,11 and 10 for columns. Refer this for more details [this](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~trnka/CISC105-04F/making_columns.html)

```
printf("Column1    Column2   Column3\n");
printf("%7d%11s%10d\n", 100, "String1", 9348);
printf("%7d%11s%10d\n", 23, "String2", 214);
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. It's really easy and it helped me to get the output like what I wanted to have. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

use printf like this :

```
printf("%-25s|\n", "a string");
printf("%-25s|\n", "another string");
```

(the - in %-25s is use to left-justifies your text)

Answer (score 0):

not a linux user (hope we are talking about monospace output) but my experienceis that `tab` has usually configurable size so if you format for `6` character length and someone have 4 character `tab` the result will be bad. The safest is to use spaces. You can use formated output like:

```
printf("float number: 8.3%f",7.56);
```

But that is not always a good choice for example sometimes negative sign mess up things ...

I usually handle such formatting my self with use of string variables:

1. `line = ""`
2. `item = "single unformated text value"`
3. compute length of `item`
4. add missing spaces (before or after) to `line` or `item`
5. add `item` to `line`
6. loop **#2** for all items
7. output `line`
8. loop **#1** for all lines